# Table Data is not showing with Pagination PHP

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Continuation question from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44490959/mysqli-query-connection-for-already-connected-page-php) with pagination.

The basic code for displaying data in the table from mysql.

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT accountno,accountname,cname,revenue,status FROM ***** WHERE user_id = ? '); 
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);  
   $stmt->bind_result($accountno ,$accountname, $cname, $revenue,$status);
    $stmt->execute();    // Execute the prepared query.
    echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Account No</th>
        <th>Account Name</th>
        <th>Company Name</th>
        <th>Revenue</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['accountno'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['accountname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['cname'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['revenue'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        echo "</table>";
```

**Problem 1:**
With this code, it failed to load data. Showing the table, Showing even the row field but no data.[image]

**Problem 2**: Adding pagination. Code Example was taken from [here](http://www.phponwebsites.com/2014/04/php-mysql-pagination.html)
Showing Notice of undefining index at this line. Also, want to is this code below is safe and okay in case of performance?

> $page=$_REQUEST['p'];

Here is the part for pagination:

```
 <?php
        //------------
        $page=$_REQUEST['p'];
      $limit=10;
       if($page=='')
    {
    $page=1;
    $start=0;
    }
else
  {
    $start=$limit*($page-1);
   }

    $total=$stmt->num_rows;
    $num_page=ceil($total/$limit);

  function pagination($page,$num_page)
  {
    echo'<ul style="list-style-type:none;">';
    for($i=1;$i<=$num_page;$i++)
 {
       if($i==$page)
    {
    echo'<li style="float:left;padding:5px;">'.$i.'</li>';
    }
    else
     {
      echo'<li style="float:left;padding:5px;"><a href="protected_page.php?
         p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
      }
          }
     echo'</ul>';
     }
     if($num_page>1)
      {
      pagination($page,$num_page);
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while( $stmt->fetch()) {

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $accountno . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $accountname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $cname . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $revenue . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $status . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
```

you are binding result but using $row to display, it wont, so try this

for pagination

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['p'])){
//then all the code for pagination
}
```

Comment: Thank you it just worked, what about the notice with $page=$_REQUEST['p'];

Comment: show the url of the pagination how you are passing it

Comment: I am testing it on localhost: http://localhost/something/protected_page.php

Comment: Do I need to add the function part also inside it?

Comment: sorry didnt get it, Its showing the data on table. But its showing the header??